# Core Animation -- Nothing Appears (OS X)

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-animation, nsview, quartz-core

I am attempting to draw this plane with Core Animation *in OS X*:

[image]

(without the black background, however).

This is the code in my custom NSView:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame
{
  self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
  if (self) {
    [self A_singlePlane];
  }
  return self;
}

- (void)A_singlePlane{
  CALayer *container = [CALayer layer];
  container.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);
  [self.layer addSublayer:container];

  CALayer *purpleLayer = [self addPlaneToLayer:container size:CGSizeMake(100, 100)   position:CGPointMake(100, 100) color:[NSColor purpleColor]];

  CATransform3D t = CATransform3DIdentity;
  t = CATransform3DRotate(t, 45.0f * M_PI / 180.f, 0, 1, 0);
  purpleLayer.transform = t;
}

- (CALayer *)addPlaneToLayer:(CALayer* )container size:(CGSize)size position:(CGPoint)point color:(NSColor *)color{

  CALayer *plane = [CALayer layer];

  plane.backgroundColor = [color CGColor];
  plane.opacity = 0.6;
  plane.frame = CGRectMake(point.x, point.y, size.width, size.height);
  plane.borderColor = [[NSColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:0.5] CGColor];
  plane.borderWidth = 3.0;
  plane.cornerRadius = 10.0;
  [container addSublayer:plane];

  return plane;
}
```

I have a view in interface builder with the class set as my custom NSView class. My custom view is set to have a layer. The result is a blank NSWindow. I do not receive any errors or warnings.

Does anyone see where my logical flaw is?

Comment: Is your custom view layer backed? (`setWantsLayer = YES`)

Comment: That worked, thanks! But I already selected in Interface Builder for  my view to have a layer, so why do I have to call it in the code too? Is the layer checkbox in Interface Builder not the same as writing it out in Objective-C?